# Are the ideals of any integral domain $R$ trivial only?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Are the ideals of any integral domain $R$ trivial only?

Comment: Of course not: what are the ideals of $\;\Bbb Z\;$ , for example?

Comment: I=(-1) is an example of a non-trivial ideal correct

Comment: No, @tamefoxes: $\;(-1)=(1)=R\;$ in any unitary ring, and it is an improper ideal (and some don't even consider it an ideal in some aspects, though it actually is by definition).

Comment: so would (2) be an ideal?

Comment: Of $\;\Bbb Z\;$ ? Indeed, @tamefoxes: it is the non-trivial *proper* ideal of all even integers.

Comment: Alright thanks @DonAntonio

Comment: How many seconds have you thought about this question before asking it here? Do you have considered a single example? What do you learn from this experience?

Comment: Obviously given the first comment and my response I didn't think of an example of an integral domain and was merely stuck in the thought of the fact that integral domains contain the identity element. Is it necessary to be condescending about asking such a question when I was stuck in a cyclical thought process?

Comment: @tamefoxes I always say that step 1 in solving any mathematics problem is to consider the simplest example, and step 2 is to consider the second-simplest example.  But I deeply apologize for any condescension that you've experienced here; some are caught in their own cyclical process of insecurity and bullying.

Comment: @ User-33433:  your remarks are well-received.  Well-put, and thanks!

Comment: Thank you @User-33433, I usually do consider the steps you have mentioned. However, this question came to me when I was answering a homework question so I was deep in thought about that question and hastily posted without further investigation in my part. Once I was given an example of an integral, I already felt that my post was unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The fact that $R$ is an integral domain is equivalent to say that the ideal $(0)$ is prime, but it doesn't tell you anything on the other ideals.

As examples you can consider:

- The ring $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers, where $n\mathbb{Z}$ is a proper ideal for every $n\neq0,1$.
- Given an integral domain $R$, then the ring $R[x]$ is again an integral domain which has infinitely many ideals (consider e.g. $(x^n)$ for $n\ge1$) independently of the ideals of $R$ (i.e. you can also take $R$ to be a field).

Answer (score 2):

No, if $R$ is not a trivial ring, i.e. $R \ne \{0 \}$, since for any $0 \ne a \in R$ the principal ideal $\langle a \rangle = aR \ne \{ 0\}$, by virtue of the fact that $R$ has no zero divisors.

It is perhaps worth noting in this context that if $R$ is an integral domain the only ideals of which are $\{ 0 \}$ and $R$ itself, then $R$ must be a field; for if take any $a \in R$, the principal ideal $\langle a \rangle = aR \ne \{ 0 \}$, so we must have $aR = R$.  Then there must exist $b \in R$ with $ab = 1$.  Thus $b = a^{-1}$ and $R$ is a field.  Conversely, any integral domain which is not a field has non-trivial, *proper* ideals, *viz.* the $aR$ for non-unit $a$.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Thanks Robert, this is exactly the question that I was answering before I made this post.

Comment: Well, good then!  Glad to help out!

Comment: Asking that the ring is a domain is superflouous since it isn't needed at all in that argument: any commutative ring (with identity) with exactly two ideals is a field.

Comment: @ rschwieb:  Dr. Schwieb!  Good to hear from you again.  And I've course you are correct; having siezed upon the Op's context, I thought of little else.  Perhaps it would help if you left him/her a similar comment?  In any event, hope 2014 finds you well.  Regards.